# For loop wont recognizwe the name of the 2d array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop

**I have a 2d array and my goal is to print the total length of the 2d array. However I get an error with this code. In the for loop header, the compiler wont recognize the name "arrays" and suggests I make a local variable with that name.**

**I have already tried to calculate the 1d arrays.length before the for loop, but that didn't work either as the compiler still didn't recognize the name "arrays"**

```
int[][] arrays = { {2, 5, 3, 8, 5},
                            {3, 5, 1, 7, 2},
                            { 6, 2, 8, 1}};
    }
    int Length = 0;
    for (int i= 0; i< arrays.length; i++) {
        Length += arrays[i].length;
    }
```

Comment: here by you have added extra bracket befor `int Length = 0;` thats why it is giving an error, because scope of function getting closed before use of that array. So please check this whenever you  any question

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati is right, due to an extra bracket, its code block is being closed before int Length=0; and compiler is assuming that the lower code is in different scopt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int[][] arrays = { {2, 5, 3, 8, 5},
            {3, 5, 1, 7, 2},
            { 6, 2, 8, 1}};

int Length = 0;
for (int i= 0; i< arrays.length; i++) {
    Length += arrays[i].length;
    System.out.println(+Length);
}
```

Comment: Add some kind of explanation/detail along with your code.

Comment: Here i have removed the curly braces before int length =0 statement so that the array.length thing in the for loop have the scope which helps us to use array been defined

Comment: Thanks. Click "Edit" button and add this in your answer for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Hi LoFitz the problem i see is that you placed the name of the array before the brackets.Instead of:

```
int[][] arrays
```

use

```
int arrays [][]
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

arrays[I][j].length

use this It may help u bruh

Comment: Please provide the proper solution with proper comments.

Comment: Try to remove the curly bracket before int length